Broadcasting a message to users in desktop environments
I'm currently writing a small systemd service that may need to shutdown the computer. I'd like to broadcast a message to all users, e.g. This computer is going to shutdown at XXX, don't forget save your work.
For terminal users, I could use wall, but for users who don't have a terminal open, that's not an option. I know that all the users on this machine use X/Gnome, so they have a freedesktop notification client installed. However, it's not clear to me how I can use the system bus (?) to send freedesktop notifications.
How can I do that?

You don't use the system bus, but the individual user's sessions!
you get all currently active user session
loginctl list-sessions

(I often do things on systemd tooling's optional JSON output. For example, here, loginctl list-session --output json | jq -r '.[].user' would just give me a list of users. `… | jq -r '.[] | select (.state == "active") | .user' give me the ones which are actively sitting in front of their screens.)
Then, you just run the notification emitter on the user bus of the target user. That's just:
systemd-run --user --machine=${userFromAbove}@.host notify-send --urgency=low 'Coffee ready!'

Throwing this into one (zsh) script:
#!/usr/bin/zsh
# (should work in bash as well)

# run yourself as root, unless you're already root.
[[ $(id -u) == "0" ]] || {sudo $0 ; exit $?}

for user in $(loginctl list-session --output json \
             | jq -r '.[] | select (.state == "active") | .user') ; do
  systemd-run \
    --user \
    --machine=${user}@.host \
    notify-send \
       --urgency=normal \
       'Fresh crumpets in the kitchen! Guy named Crud Puppy dropped them off.'
done


Thanks! It was my understanding that notify-send requires a DISPLAY and a DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS, was I wrong?

notify send does not itself interact with the display – it just sends a notification to the thing that runs and displays the notifications (which already has access to the display). The session bus is exactly what you get when you run things with systemd-run --user. That's why we do it here. Have you tried it?

Oh, it absolutely works, I'm just trying to understand why :)

glad to hear it works, @Yoric! Did my comment answer your questions, then?

Yes, it did, thanks a lot!
